# No pyvenv.cfg file in poetry installation (brand new computer)

Tags: python-poetry

I have a brand-spanking new machine (Windows 10 Pro).  I have never run any python ever on it.  I have a project which I have downloaded which uses poetry which is some sort of environment configuration thing which I have also never heard of.

I realized upon looking at the code that I needed this poetry thing, so I googled how to install it.  What I found was this command:

```
(Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://install.python-poetry.org -UseBasicParsing).Content | python -
```

This command was to be run from Powershell, however it failed initially because Python was not found. I looked inside the pyproject.toml file and saw that it was dependent on python 3.8 so I went to the Microsoft Store and installed this version.  That went well.  I then retried the command listed above to install poetry.

This failed and referenced an error log file which I found and opened.  The file is pretty short, all it says is:

```
No pyvenv.cfg file


Traceback:

  File "<stdin>", line 919 in main
  File "<stdin>", line 552 in run
```

Upon googling for this error/problem I have found a couple of references, but they are not relevant for my use case.  Rather than trying things randomly, I am wondering if someone can just point me in the right direction to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this guy figured it out already:

[python poetry installation failed on Windows 10 - no pyvenv.cfg file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70723486/python-poetry-installation-failed-on-windows-10-no-pyvenv-cfg-file)

Basically go to this site: https://www.python.org/downloads/ and reinstall python.  no idea why it works but it does.  Note, I had to close and reopen powershell for this to work.